# Projective modules over enveloping algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, noncommutative-algebra, projective-module

How could I prove the following statement?

Let $k$ a commutative ring and let $A$ an associative $k$-algebra that is also a projective $k$-module. Then every projective $A\otimes A^{op}$ left module is also a projective $A$-left module (and a projective $A$- right module).

Comment: Use the characterization of projective modules as direct summands of free modules?

Comment: @darijgrinberg I don't see how, because I want to obtain projective $A$-modules, not $k$-modules

Comment: Let $L$ be a projective $A\otimes A^{op}$-left module. Then, $L$ is a direct summand of $\left(A\otimes A^{op}\right)^{\oplus n}$ for some cardinal $n$. But $A^{op}$ is a projective $k$-module, and thus a direct addend of a free $k$-module. Hence, $A\otimes A^{op}$ is a direct addend of $A$ tensored by a free $k$-module. That means that $A\otimes A^{op}$ is a direct addend of a free left $A$-module. Thus, the same holds for $\left(A\otimes A^{op}\right)^{\oplus n}$, and therefore also for its direct summand $L$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A direct summand of a projective module is projective, and an arbitrary direct sum of projective modules is projective, so it is enough to do this for $P=A\otimes_kA$, and then it is obvious!

Comment: Indeed, as $A\otimes A$ is projective as a left $A$-module, every direct sum of copies of $A\otimes A$ is projective as a left $A$-module, and therefore every direct summand of every direct sum of copies of $A\otimes A$ is projective as a left $A$-module. That is, every projective $A\otimes A$-module is projective as a left $A$-module.

Comment: Yes, thanks, this is what darij grinberg wrote in a comment.
An observation without relevance: is $A\otimes A^{op}$, not $A\otimes A$.

Comment: I know. As you say, that is irrelevant.

Comment: In any case, one does not usually write the OP when refering to the module, as opposed to the ring.